# Filter Map object values from ArrayList

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an object similar to the following:

```json
{
  "list": [
    {
      "price": "50",
      "items": {
        "XYZ": {
          "price": "6",
          "id": "1212121"
        },
        "details": {},
        "id": "1647308"
      }
    },
    {
      "price": "20",
      "items": {
        "XYZ": {
          "price": "10",
          "id": "1212121"
        },
        "details": {},
        "id": "1647308"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```java
public class List {
   private string price;
   private List<Item> items;
   private string id;
}

public class Item {
    private Map<String, BonusItem> bonusItem;
}

public BonusItem
{
 private string price;

}
```

From the above list I need to fetch the array object inside "items"-> "XYZ", and the output should be something like below. I am trying using a Java stream.

```json
[
   {
      "price":"10",
      "id":"1212121"
   },
   {
      "price":"6",
      "id":"1212121"
   }
]
```

I tried couple of options and getting compile error with lambda and I am new to Java and `Map` objects.

Comment: it's hard to help without knowing the class structure, as the lambda streams will be operating on that. If it's just straightforward classes with typical getters, you should be able to achieve the result with `list.stream().map(e -> e.getItems().getXYZ()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Thank you. I can post the class structure tomorrow. 

Map<string, class>
 “Xyz” is map key and value is  {
          "price": "6",
          "id": "1212121"
        }.

Comment: @ODDminus1 I have updated the post with class details.

Comment: I was able to get it. Thank you @ODDminus1 your sample gave me an idea and developed from there to accomplish and get it done.

Comment: @Coder2023 If you found a working solution based on the help you received here, it would be good to add it as an answer.  That's a good way to give back to the community that helped you, and it can help others who run across this question in the future.